# How to secure chat's data in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to secure my database and i want to secure the messages.
My structure is messages/{chatid}/chat/messageArray (the chatid is like userid1-userid2). So i would like to check in security rules if chatid contain userid. I tried something it's working in simulator but i have a problem because in my code i query collection group and firestore deny acces. I make something like db.collection("messages").where("users", "array-contains", user.uid).onSnapshot.....
If someone know how can i secure messages data i could be great.

```
match /messages/{chatId}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if chatId.matches('.*'+request.auth.uid+'.*');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule you're showing here does not match your example query.  The rule can only match documents in a subcollection of documents in the messages collection.  Your query is trying to read documents immediately in the messages collection.  The glob wildcard can **not** match zero path components.  [Only in rules version 2 can a glob wildcard match nothing.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

Your options are to either set the `rules_version = '2';` at the first line of your rules, or add another rule that matches documents in messages without using a glob wildcard:

```
match /messages/{chatId} {
  allow read, write: if chatId.matches('.*'+request.auth.uid+'.*');
}
```

I will encourage you instead not to try to match on the contents of `chatId`, and instead use fields of the documents.  Your query should also use those fields to filter queries.  This is more straightforward.